# why is gzip trying to compress itself

Tags: gzip, ksh, aix

Attempting to run gzip from a command prompt to compress any file returns

```
gzip: /usr/bin/gzip is not a directory or a regular file - ignored
```

as the first line of output.

Here's what I can think of to share that may shed some light:

```
oslevel  
7.1.0.0

echo $SHELL  
/usr/bin/ksh  

gzip -V
gzip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93)
Compilation options:
DIRENT UTIME STDC_HEADERS HAVE_UNISTD_H
```

To produce the error, all I have to do is try to compress any file with gzip (i.e. gzip test.out).  The error occurs when run from the command prompt as well as when run from cron.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Additional requsted information:

```
gzip -h  
gzip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93)  
usage: gzip [-cdfhlLnNrtvV19] [-S suffix] [file ...]  
 -c --stdout      write on standard output, keep original files unchanged  
 -d --decompress  decompress  
 -f --force       force overwrite of output file and compress links  
 -h --help        give this help  
 -l --list        list compressed file contents  
 -L --license     display software license  
 -n --no-name     do not save or restore the original name and time stamp  
 -N --name        save or restore the original name and time stamp  
 -q --quiet       suppress all warnings  
 -r --recursive   operate recursively on directories  
 -S .suf  --suffix .suf     use suffix .suf on compressed files  
 -t --test        test compressed file integrity  
 -v --verbose     verbose mode  
 -V --version     display version number  
 -1 --fast        compress faster  
 -9 --best        compress better  
 file...          files to (de)compress. If none given, use standard input.  

file /usr/bin/gzip  
/usr/bin/gzip: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module

gzip *.out
gzip: /usr/bin/gzip is not a directory or a regular file - ignored  

gzip -d *.gz
gzip: /usr/bin/gzip is not a directory or a regular file - ignored
```

Comment: What does `file /usr/bin/gzip` tell you? And can you add the output of `gzip -h`?

Comment: file gzip

file: 0653-900 cannot open gzip.


gzip -h
gzip 1.2.4 (18 Aug 93)
usage: gzip [-cdfhlLnNrtvV19] [-S suffix] [file ...]
 -c --stdout      write on standard output, keep original files unchanged
 -d --decompress  decompress
 -f --force       force overwrite of output file and compress links
 -h --help        give this help
...

Comment: Please [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27944510/edit) your question instead with that extra information. It is much clearer.

Comment: Sorry, that command should have been `file /usr/bin/gzip`; what does that tell you?

Comment: /usr/bin/gzip: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module

Comment: Have you defined any shell aliases?

Comment: There are no aliases that reference gzip.

Comment: Is it any better at unzipping itself? :-)

Comment: Mark, that was an interesting question.  Unfortunately, the answer is no.  I tried "gzip -d *.gz" and the only line that showed up was  "gzip: /usr/bin/gzip is not a directory or a regular file - ignored", however, the file was unzipped.

Comment: what if you use anything but the korn shell, like plain sh or csh?

Comment: I just realized: This is from 1993, which is older than any gzip I've ever put my fingers on -- so this might be a version that's NOT GNU gzip, but just gratis zip -- I'm absolutely not familiar with RS/6000, so my advice is actually worth NIL here.

Comment: Ok, well poking around on other lpars and I have found one that appears to have the same version of gzip and the error is not produced.  Must be something set up on the system.  I'll post back if I figure out what the difference is that is causing the error.  Any pointers about what to look at would be appreciated, as I'm currently stumped.

Comment: gzip 1.2.4 is in fact GNU gzip.

Comment: This is odd.  It seems like it is interpreting argv[0] as argv[1] for some reason.  Did you compile it yourself?  Did you make any changes?

Comment: I did not compile it myself.  One of our team of UNIX admins would be able to take credit for that.  I did attempt to download gzip-1.6, but could not get it unzipped.  So I dropped back to 1.3.9, which was only a .tar file.  I attempted to compile it, but ran into: ///usr/include/sys/stat.h:448: error: conflicting types for 'futimens'
utimens.h:2: error: previous declaration of 'futimens' was here
utimens.c: In function 'utimens':
utimens.c:186: warning: passing argument 2 of 'futimens' from incompatible pointer type
utimens.c:186: error: too many arguments to function 'futimens'

Comment: So, it turns out the issue is not due to how we compiled it as the executable was dl'd from IBM and is the most current binary they are posting for use.  Anyhow, the SA can run gzip on the same lpar without issue.  When he does a simple sudo, it runs without error.  If he does a sudo where it executes our .profile, he gets the error.  So, it appears to be something with the account specifically.  Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:
We have an environment file where we load common environment variables.  One line in the file is

```
export GZIP="/usr/bin/gzip"
```

According to the gzip documentation, the GZIP environment variable is used to specify options. So, it's probably taking that as part of the command line. And, since it's not really an option, it's interpreting the value as being a file name, which it can't gzip because it's actually a symbolic link. By unsetting the variable, the error goes away.